# Scala3 "sbt doc" AssertionError when extending Iterator[_]

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

The following Scala 3 code generates an Assertion error when I execute the `sbt doc` command. The error only occurs with `extends Iterator[Bar]` and not other `extends`, e.g. `extends Iterable[Bar]`.

```
trait Bar

object Foo extends Iterator[Bar]:
  override def hasNext: Boolean = ???
  override def next(): Bar      = ???
```

The program itself is running as expected; the problem is AFAICS only related to `sbt doc`.

Any thoughts or insights would be appreciated.

The first few lines of the exception are:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.7.1 (Oracle Corporation Java 17.0.1)
[info] loading global plugins from ...\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] loading project definition from ...\docfailexample\project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to docfailexample (in build file:/.../docfailexample/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 5 Nov 2022, 2:50:24 pm
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to ...\docfailexample\target\scala-3.2.0\classes ...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to ...\docfailexample\target\scala-3.2.0\api...
[info] Skipping unused scalacOptions: -Werror
Problem parsing src\main\scala\Main.scala:<0..124>, documentation may not be generated.
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
  | => rat scala.runtime.Scala3RunTime$.assertFailed(Scala3RunTime.scala:11)
        at dotty.tools.dotc.util.Spans$Span$.start$extension(Spans.scala:45)
        at dotty.tools.dotc.util.SourcePosition.start(SourcePosition.scala:52)
        at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$PositionMethods$.start(QuotesImpl.scala:2813)
        at scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl$reflect$PositionMethods$.start(QuotesImpl.scala:2813)
        at dotty.tools.scaladoc.tasty.ClassLikeSupport.getParentsAsTreeSymbolTuples$$anonfun$1(ClassLikeSupport.scala:260)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$6.hasNext(Iterator.scala:472)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.prependedAll(List.scala:152)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$.from(List.scala:684)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$.from(List.scala:681)
        at scala.collection.IterableOps$WithFilter.map(Iterable.scala:891)
```

Comment: Issue posted in dotty github repo https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/16290

Answer (score 0):

This was a defect and fixed in the Scala 3.3.0-RC2 release.